# How to giving variable spacing between word in tcl?

Tags: list, tcl

I just started learning Tcl, my main objective to print the two lists like this:

```
List1             List2
1                 A
2                 B
3                 C
4                 D
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a loop and [`format`](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/format.htm):

```
set List1 {1 2 3 4}
set List2 {A B C D}
puts [format %-10s%-10s List1 List2]
foreach i $List1 j $List2 {
    puts [format %-10s%-10s $i $j]
}
```

Output from the above:

```
List1     List2
1         A
2         B
3         C
4         D
```

Note: In the above, `%-10s` roughly means left align the text within a column of 10 spaces

Comment: If you change the `%-10s` to `%-18s`, you will get exactly the same result as in your question.